# Should I bind to a "dormant" object at designtime in XAML or wait until runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, observablecollection

I want to bind my ListView to the results of a query. The query does not fire until the user enters some text and selects a button, though. Should I in this scenario create the binding on the fly programmatically?

Or should I bind to an ObservableCollection (or...???) at design-time (in XAML) that will provide the data, although at least at first the object bound to will not yet have been 
populated with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not bind a *query* to a control. Instead, bind the actual objects after they've been retrieved from the DB. So, use an `ObservableCollection` that you populate after the query has been completed.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345389/870604) for the justification.